# Javascript library that supports RSA-OAEP with MGF Hash

Tags: library, javascript, encryption

Is there any chance that some Javascript library exists, where you can decrypt and encrypt with MGF Hash flag and so on?
I have some encryption made in the PHP, with some libraries (Crypt_RSA) which and I want to transfer to Javascript.

Thank you very much!